# Equivalent of MKPolyline in iOS 3

Tags: iphone, ios, polyline, ios-3.x

In iOS 4 when I need to build a polyline I use code like this:

```
MKPolyline  *polyLine=[MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:[points count]];
```

But with iOS 3 (3.1.3) it doesn't work...

What is the equivalent for iOS 3? Or what is the right way to build a polyline for iOS3?

Answer (score 0):

MKPolyline is only available in iOS 4.0 and later. There's no (documented, at least) support in iOS 3.1.

Comment: I think I have found a way for that ... take a look at : http://navarra.ca/?p=786 and it work!

Answer (score 0):

[Craig Spitzkoff](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65) found a way to display a polyline on a map using an annotation. [William Lachance](http://navarra.ca/?p=786) built on that in his [nvpolyline](https://github.com/wlach/nvpolyline) project.